# Project Server 2013 Readers group empty after project publish

Tags: project-server

Last few days I installed SharePoint 2013 and Project Server 2013 Updates from windows update, I configured the updates successfully.

I noticed that the Readers group in the root PWA site becomes empty if any of the project managers publish a project.

Knowing that the Project Site permissions are OK, and I enabled the Project site permissions and root PWA permissions sync.

Currently I used to run `Sync-SPProjectPermissions -Url http://url/epm -SyncPWASite -Async` Command to overcome this issue. but I need to check every second that or the users will get `Access Denied` error when trying to access the site

Comment: Same problem for us. Any updates on that bug ?
Does it concern one specific project ? Thanks.